# Number of arrangements of $5$ boys and $4$ girls such that all $4$ girls do not come together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $9$ students of which $5$ are boys and $4$ are girls and we have to find the number of arrangements of all the $9$ students in such a way that all the $4$ girls do not come together.

I came this far:I know that there are $6$ places for each girl to sit on. But according to the question the can be three types of cases:

1. when every girl sits alone
2. when two girls sit together
3. when $3$ girls sit together

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: But how to show?Should I just type my effort.

Comment: @user582329 Yes, exactly.  Show how far you've gotten, so we can see what your difficulty is.

Comment: I know that there are 6 places for each girl to sit on. But according to the question the can be three types of cases 1)when every girl sits alone.2)when two girls sit together.3)when 3girls sit together.

Comment: But I dont know how to find the no. Of cases for each of it.So that I can add them

Comment: Hint:  it's easier to work backwards.  Find the number of arrangements with no restrictions, then find the number in which all the girls sit together and subtract.

Comment: Is the answer 36

Comment: Building off lulu's comment: have you ever worked with the principle of inclusion-exclusion? I think I recall working on a problem similar to this, and that approach should give you a reasonable idea of how the computation will work.

Comment: Even assuming you meant to say that all the boys (resp. girls) are indistinguishable from one another there are still considerably more than $36$ good patterns.  There are $\binom 73=35$ that begin $GB\cdots$, and there are another $\binom 62 = 15$ that begin $GGB\cdots$, for example.

Comment: As lulu indicated, it is easier to work backwards.  If you try to do the problem directly, note that you also have to consider the possibility that there are two separate pairs of girls who sit together.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the boys and girls are distinguishable.

The answer is very simple : in any arrangement of boys and girls, either : all  four girls come together, or ; all the four girls don't come together.

Therefore, since you are trying to figure out the number of arrangements where the girls do not sit together, you must simply do this : find the total number of arrangements, and subtract from this the number of arrangements in which the girls sit together.

The total number of arrangements is $9!$, since you are arranging nine objects in total.

The number of arrangements in which all the girls sit together can be calculated like this : first, pick where the leftmost girl sits : she must sit in positions $1 \to 6$ if the positions are numbered $1,...,9$. Now, the positions of all the girls are fixed, and they can be permuted in these positions in $4!$ ways. Similarly, the positions of the other boys is fixed, and they can be permuted in $5!$ ways. Hence, the answer is $6 \times 4! \times 5! = 4! \times 6!$.

Therefore, the answer is $9! - 4!6! = 345600$. As you can see, this is a lot more than the $36$ you have written.

---

If the boys and girls are indistinguishable, then the total number of arrangements is $\binom 94$, since we are picking $4$ positions out of $9$ which the girls will occupy, and the number of disallowed positions will just be $6$ of them, since the girls and boys can't be permuted amongst themselves now. So the answer is $\binom 94 - 6 = 120$.